# insert image with drawImage(page, docu, x, y, ximage, fRatioImage)

Tags: java, pdfbox

i have to insert image with `drawImage(page, docu, x, y, ximage, fRatioImage)`, until now I can insert the image with this function, but the problem is that the image is shifted relative to the `x` and `y` coordinates.
does anyone knows the unit of measurement used by this function to the point `(x, y)`?
this is the code that i use :

```
PDDocument docu=docu = PDDocument.load(filedoc);
inputStream in = ImageSignature.is;
biimage=ImageIO.read(in);
PDPage page = (PDPage)docu.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get( 0 );
PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDJpeg(docu, biimage );
PdfBoxImageUtil.drawImage(page, docu, x, y, ximage, fRatioImage);
```

Comment: Where is this method from?

Comment: this function is from the package pdfbox,it use this function PDPageContentStream(objMapping, (float) x, (float) y, (float) width, 
(float) height)

Comment: The OP means Apache PDFBox, added the tag

Comment: There is no class PdfBoxImageUtil in pdfbox API. At least I did not found it. And google have problems finding it too!

Comment: this class PdfBoxImageUtil just call method from pdfbox it call this methode:contentStream.drawXObject( objMapping, (float) x, 
(float) y, (float) width, (float) height);

Comment: i think that the unit of mesure of the function is 'computer point (pt) or the (PostScript point)'